# KafkaTemplate blocks although returning a ListenableFuture

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka 1.1.2. Whenever I call the send method of KafkaTemplate returning a ListenableFuture it blocks.

Looking into the source code of KafkaProducer it actually seems to be intended that way - I found calls to methods named "waitOnMetadata".

Am I missing something obvious? How can I avoid to block when sending a record to Kafka?

Comment: Spring Kafka is fully based on the Apache Kafka. So, if you see that `KafkaProducer` is blocked, that already isn't a question to Spring Kafka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kafka producer code is invoked on the calling thread; the listenable future is to receive the confirmation from Kafka that the message was received.

There is a [reactor-kafka](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka) project, which might help.

We intend to base a future version of Spring Kafka on that.

Comment: Thanks. It would be great to have that information in the JavaDoc as well as in the reference documentation.